# How can I convert UIButton to UISlider when it is touched?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, swift5

I've been trying to figure out, how to convert `UIButton` to `UISlider`. I have added music on the `UIButton`, and I want to convert it into `UIslider` when it's touched.  How can I do that?

Comment: Why don't you show what you have tried already?

Answer (score 0):

put your slider under your button then you can hide button when it touch and show your slider
also you can add animation when show or hide button or slider

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can't convert a `UIButton` to a `UISlider` (:D :D)

Approach:

- Add Slider and Button on the same place on storyboard
- in `viewDidLoad()`

```
button.isHidden = false 
slider.isHidden = true 
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapped), for: .touchUpInside)
```

```
@objc private func tapped() {
    button.isHidden = true 
    slider.isHidden = false  
}
```